# Maps.jar decompiled source for Android?

Tags: android

Is there a way for me to get google Android 2.2 source for the maps.jar ? Wanted to see how MyLocationOverlay works so I can extend and override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps source code is not available for Android

But maybe you can see an use of what you are looking for [here](http://code.google.com/p/geohunter/source/browse/trunk/GeoHunter/src/org/geohunter/activity/map/FixedMyLocationOverlay.java?r=283)

About MyLocationOverlay all you can see is the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)

Comment: actually want i meant was MyLocationOverlay, i wanted to see whats in it

Comment: @user492182 I added a link to the documentation (that you probably saw already).